# objective-c BAD ACCESS in recursion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, recursion, exc-bad-access

c function which gets me a BAD ACCESS error during execution: (I left out the actually working part of the function for ease of reading, the error appears in this code snippet as well)

```
- (void) recursiveClearUpToH2:(NSXMLElement *)rootElement
{
    NSXMLNode *currNode = [[NSXMLNode alloc] init];
    currNode = [rootElement childAtIndex:0];
    [self recursiveClearUpToH2:currNode];
}
```

The error appears in the first line "NSXML...". Funny thing is that always appears in a different recursion.

---

Hoping to improve benefit of my question to others, I wrote another app which reproduces the same error in a simpler way:
main.m:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "TestObj.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    TestObj *testObj = [[TestObj alloc] init];
    NSInteger *i =1;
    [testObj recTest:i];
    return 0;
}
```

TestObj.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestObj : NSObject
- (void)recTest:(NSInteger *)recCount;
@end
```

TestObj.m:

```
#import "TestObj.h"

@implementation TestObj
- (void)recTest:(NSInteger *)recCount
{
    recCount += 1;
    NSXMLNode *currNode = [[NSXMLNode alloc] init];
    if (recCount < 100) {
        TestObj *testObj = [[TestObj alloc] init];
        [testObj recTest:recCount];
    }
}
@end
```

changing the line in TestObj.m from

```
NSXMLNode *currNode = [[NSXMLNode alloc] init];
```

to

```
NSXMLNode *currNode;
```

solved the problem for me.

Thanks for your support :)

Comment: This is clearly infinite recursion, therefore sooner or later your app will crash when it is out of memory.

Comment: As @Sulthan points out - this code is an infinite recursion; nothing in the code stops the execution and thus, when the app runs out of memory, it will crash.

Comment: The alloc / init is completely pointless.

Comment: You have no idea how to work with pointers...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

basing on gnasher729's (thanks to you) comment:

changing the line in TestObj.m from

```
NSXMLNode *currNode = [[NSXMLNode alloc] init];
```

to

```
NSXMLNode *currNode;
```

solved the problem for me.

Thanks for your support :)